# XFS On VMware VM Fails With Bad Magic Number

Tags: filesystems, vmware-vsphere, xfs

I have almost exactly the same problem as described [here](http://oss.sgi.com/archives/xfs/2015-01/msg00503.html).

I am on RHEL7.
3.10.0-229.4.2.el7.x86_6
Inside vmware VM.

```
file -s /dev/sdb 
/dev/sdb: LVM2 PV (Linux Logical Volume Manager), UUID: 89o2LY-bTso-5KXa-UXOF-CVm0-gT1u-DsKNpH, size: 107374510080
```

Also get the message:
Metadata corruption detected at xfs_inode_buf_verify+0x75/0xd0 [xfs], block 0x2d01c10
XFS (dm-2): Unmount and run xfs_repair

After running repair I see the same message:

```
Phase 1 - find and verify superblock...
couldn't verify primary superblock - bad magic number !!!
attempting to find secondary superblock...

…

Found candidate secondary superblock…
Unable to verify superblock, continuing…
And on it goes until it eventually gives up.
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**
I am not exactly sure what might have happened. This is a Cassandra node which was rebooted from within the operating system. The last messages before xfs corruption were those of Cassandra trying to create some directories.

Comment: What happened _before_ you submitted this question? It's rare for the OS or XFS to corrupt itself without cause, so can you explain what happened to the system?